# Getting the value of a selected listview

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, arraylist

I have a screen that shows user's information in a 3 listview columnn, I get the data for each listview from  3 arraylist, each arraylist contains data from xml that I parsed using DOM parser. 
for the first listview, I want the user to be able to click on it, get the value of the listview item(its a string), and get navigated to another screen based on the value of the single item selected.
E.G. the arraylist will contain ( A,B,C,D,...), so the listview will have ( A,B,C,D), if the user clicked on B> the user should be navigated to screen B(I'm gonna have a query that uses the value of that list item)

ViewMyTickets.java

```
    public class ViewMyTickets extends ListActivity  {


        public static String buttonText;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_view_my_tickets);


        string theirID = xmlresult// this is the xml result i get from web services


try {
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf =
        DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource is = new InputSource();
    is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(theirID));

    Document doc = db.parse(is);

    //All the UDSObjects
    NodeList nodesUDSObjectList = doc.getElementsByTagName("UDSObject");
    // iterate the UDSObjects
    Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    List<String> valSetOne = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> valSetTwo = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> valSetThree = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < nodesUDSObjectList.getLength(); i++) {
       Element elementUDSObject = (Element) nodesUDSObjectList.item(i);
       //You have a UDSObjects now
       NodeList nodesAttributeList = elementUDSObject.getElementsByTagName("Attribute");
       //You have a list of the attributes for UDSObject(i)
       // iterate the Attributes of the elementUDSObject(i)
        for (int iA = 0; iA < nodesAttributeList.getLength(); iA++) {
            Element elementAttribute = (Element) nodesAttributeList.item(iA);
            //You have attribute(iA)
            NodeList AttrNameElementList = (NodeList) elementAttribute.getElementsByTagName("AttrName");
            String nameValue = getCharacterDataFromElement((Element)(AttrNameElementList.item(0)));

            System.out.println("name"+nameValue);
            NodeList AttrValueElementList = (NodeList) elementAttribute.getElementsByTagName("AttrValue");
            String valueValue = getCharacterDataFromElement((Element)(AttrValueElementList.item(0)));
            System.out.println("value"+valueValue);
            if(nameValue.equals("ref_num")){
                valSetOne.add(valueValue);
            }
            if(nameValue.equals("summary")){
                valSetTwo.add(valueValue);
            }
            if(nameValue.equals("customer.combo_name2")){
                valSetThree.add(valueValue);
            }


        }
    }
    map.put("ref_num", valSetOne);
    map.put("summary",valSetTwo);
    map.put("customer",valSetThree);




 ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewrequest);
 myListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, valSetOne));

 myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
             int position, long id) {
         // getting values from selected ListItem
         String name = ((Button) view.findViewById(R.id.requestnumberbutton)).getText().toString();

         // Starting new intent
         Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewRequest.class);
         in.putExtra("name",name);
         startActivity(in);

     }

 });

 ListView myListView2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewrequest2);
 myListView2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listview_request2, valSetTwo));


ListView myListView3 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewrequest3);
myListView3.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listview_request3, valSetThree));









}
```

So when i run the application, and click on

```
E/AndroidRuntime(24691): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(24691): Process: com.datacom.studentproject.caservicedesk, PID: 24691
E/AndroidRuntime(24691): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.datacom.studentproject.caservicedesk/com.datacom.studentproject.caservicedesk.ViewMyTickets}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
E/AndroidRuntime(24691):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
E/AndroidRuntime(24691):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2365)
E/AndroidRuntime(24691):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:164)
E/AndroidRuntime(24691):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1258)
```

UPDATE
I've changed ListActivity to Activity, I can run the page now but when I click on a list item it crashes and i get this error in my logcat

```
E/AndroidRuntime(2714): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(2714): Process: com.datacom.studentproject.caservicedesk, PID: 2714
E/AndroidRuntime(2714): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(2714):     at com.studentproject.caservicedesk.ViewMyTickets$1.onItemClick(ViewMyTickets.java:179)
E/AndroidRuntime(2714):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:308)
E/AndroidRuntime(2714):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1478)
```

Line 179 is this

```
 String name = ((Button) view.findViewById(R.id.requestnumberbutton)).getText().toString();
```

This is my viewMyTickets.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical" >




      <ListView

        android:id="@+id/listviewrequest"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </ListView>



      </RelativeLayout>





        <RelativeLayout

            android:layout_below="@+id/lower_linear_layout"

            android:layout_width="700dp"

            android:layout_height="fill_parent"

            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">



                <ListView

        android:id="@+id/listviewrequest2"

        android:layout_width="700dp"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >            

    </ListView>           





           </RelativeLayout>  



          <RelativeLayout

            android:layout_below="@+id/lower_linear_layout"

            android:layout_width="350dp"

            android:layout_height="fill_parent"

            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">





                <ListView

        android:id="@+id/listviewrequest3"

        android:layout_width="350dp"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >            

    </ListView>           

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is whats inside the first listview 
listviewrequest.xml

```
<Button

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:id="@+id/requestnumberbutton"

    android:layout_width="180dp"

    android:layout_height="50dp"

    android:text="@+id/requestnumberbutton"

    android:textStyle="bold" 

    android:textColor="#0077FF"

    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:onClick="onClick"/>
```

PLEASE HELP ME, I REALLY NEED HELP

Comment: change this `ListActivity` to `Activity ` if you already have the listView in your layout then no need to extend it with `ListActivity`

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin I did, i can open the screen but it crashes when i select an item list, please look at the update in my post

Comment: Post your layout file

Comment: I posted whats in line 179 and the layout, please have a look, i really appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

As seen from your logcat because you have extended listActivity your listview's id should be:

```
android:id="@android:id/list"//correct
```

I guess your id is something like:

```
android:id="@+id/list"//wrong
```

Comment: I changed to this  android:id="@android:id/listviewrequest"  but i get a red line and this is the error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@android:id/listviewrequest').

Comment: @user3792722 you dont have to use findViewById when extending listActivity see this link for details http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

Answer (score 0):

When your Activity extends ListActivity use listview in this way

In Xml listview id

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

In Java get listview reference

```
ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

OR

```
ListView myListView = getListView();
```

Answer (score 0):

See this line:

```
 ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewrequest);
```

If your `ListView` id is like `android:id="@android:id/list"` then you dont have to take `ListView` object. you can directly set adatper using `setListAdapter(adapter)`

OR

You have to change `extends ListActivity` to `extends Activity`

If any question, feel free to ask.

Comment: I've changed extends ListActivity to extends Activity, I can open the screen(it doesn't crash) but when I click on a listitem it crashes.